# When do the first NCAA Football Polls come out?

Tags: american-football, collegiate

Does anyone know when the first AP polls for NCAA Football are announced?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From the [AP](https://twitter.com/AP_Top25/status/1021424466692399104?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw%7Ctwcamp%5Etweetembed%7Ctwterm%5E1021424466692399104&ref_url=https%3A%2F%2Ffansided.com%2F2018%2F07%2F23%2Fcollege-football-2018-preseason-ap-poll-date%2F) itself on 23 July 2018 regarding the 2018 AP poll:

> SAVE THE DATES: The preseason Top 25 will be released on Monday, Aug. 20, at noon Eastern, four weeks from today.
>
> The preseason AP All-America team will be released 24 hours later.